# Pandas find most bought item given ClientID ItemID ItemQuantity

Tags: python, pandas

Among the columns of my DataFrame I have ClientID CartID FoodID Quantity, I would like to find what is the food that the client has bought the most.

I tried this:

```
df.groupby(["ClientID", "FoodID"])['Quantity'].sum().max(level=['ClientID', 'FoodID']).reset_index()
```

But got a completely wrong output:

```
    Client  FoodID  Quantity
1   10      16008   24
2   10      17021   36
3   10      20665   6
4   10      20719   40
... ... ... ...
267610  200 84920   4
267611  200 85039   96
267612  200 85039   120
267613  200 85040   48
267614  200 85173   48
```

EDIT: I also tried

```
mbi.groupby("ClientID")["Quantity"].max()
```

but this results in a pair (ClientID, Quantity of the most bought food), I need (Client, FoodID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(["ClientID", "FoodID"])['Quantity'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(
    ["ClientID", 'Quantity'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(
    ["ClientID"]).sort_values('ClientID')
```

First get a df with contains the total `Quantity` for each `ClientID`, `FoodID` combination. Then sort the df on `ClientID`, `Quantity` so that highest `Quantity` per client appears on the top and finally drop the duplicates per client which will drop all the clients records except the top which happens to be max quantity.

Test case:

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ClientID' : np.random.randint(1,10, 1000),
    'FoodID' : np.random.randint(1,10, 1000),
    'Quantity' : np.random.randint(1,10, 1000),
})

df.groupby(["ClientID", "FoodID"])['Quantity'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(
    ["ClientID", 'Quantity'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(
    ["ClientID"]).sort_values('ClientID')
```

Output:

```
    ClientID    FoodID  Quantity
3   1           4       97
16  2           8       82
26  3           9       100
35  4           9       98
44  5           9       85
47  6           3       107
54  7           1       94
69  8           7       107
73  9           2       109
```

Comment: this is the same output that I got with what I first tried in the question

Comment: @ninazzo are you sure because with `drop_duplicates(["ClientID"]` part you should not be seeing duplicate `ClientIDs`

Comment: Do you know how can I fix the index column now?  Calling reset_index also adds a column named index with the old indices

Comment: @ninazzo add `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

as in your comment to handle sum of `FoodID` per `ClientID`, you just need another groupby for `sum` before the groupby of `idxmax`. This will return tuples. Pass these tuples of max `ClientID`, `FoodID` to construct a dataframe.

```
ix = df.groupby(['ClientID', 'FoodID']).Quantity.sum().groupby(level=0).idxmax()
df_final = pd.DataFrame(ix.tolist(), columns=['ClientID', 'FoodID'])

Out[58]:
   ClientID  FoodID
0         1       4
1         2       8
2         3       9
3         4       9
4         5       9
5         6       3
6         7       1
7         8       7
8         9       2
```

---

**Original:**

Use `idxmax` to get the index of each group of `ClientID` on the max value of `Quantity`. After having the indices of max `Quantity` of each group, pass it to `loc` to get the corresponding rows and columns.

docs of [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```
ix = df.groupby('ClientID').Quantity.idxmax()
df_final = df.loc[ix, ["ClientID", "FoodID"]]
```

Comment: Can you add a simple explanation, please?

Comment: I think this answer is wrong because the quantity aren't summed up, this just gives the item bought in largest quantity in a one time shopping session.

Comment: @ninazzo: oh, I misunderstand your question. The fix is simple. However, you already accepted the other answer, so I will delete this answer.

Comment: No, keep it since I find it very useful

Comment: Possibly add the fix so I'll compare the results to be sure everything is working fine

Comment: @ninazzo: I added the fix. I use the sample data from your accepted answer to show the output.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give what you want:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['ClientID', 'FoodID'], values='Quantity', aggfunc='sum').groupby('ClientID').max()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it gives me a pair of (ClientID, Quantity of the most bought food), I need (Client, Id of the most bought food)

Answer (score 0):

After groupby you can use "nlargest" method.

```
 df.groupby(["ClientID", "FoodID"])['Quantity'].sum().nlargest(1)
```

Comment: I got this error "nlargest() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'"

Comment: All right! Omit 'columns' argument from nlargest().  I edited my answer.